# *args calling plt.plot() for each optional argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, duplicates, arguments

I'm having some trouble with passing an arbitrary number of arguments to `plt.plot()`. For each  argument I try to pass via `*args` my function calls `plt.plot()` two times creating duplicates for each optional argument. The `read_n_plot` function is meant to read some datafile, spit out the data as lists, and create a plot of said data. If I want to create a plot of an XRD standard for a crystal I want to make it easily distinguishable from whatever experimental data I'm comparing it with.

From what I understand `*args` is a tuple containing all the arguments passed to my function. But I can't seem to figure out how to pass everything inside *args as is, and not calling `plt.plot(arg1) -> plt.plot(arg2) ->` etc

Got any hints I could try?

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#def read_n_plot(datafile, color, thickness, style = '-', *args):
def read_n_plot(datafile, *args, **kwargs):
    vinkel = []
    intensitet = []
    with open(datafile, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
        if datafile.endswith('.int'):
            next(f); next(f)
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line and line[0].isalpha():
                continue
            data = line.split()
            theta, counts = float(data[0]), float(data[1])
            vinkel.append(theta)
            intensitet.append(counts)
    intensitet_norm = [i/max(intensitet) for i in intensitet]
    plt.plot(vinkel, intensitet_norm, label = datafile, *args, **kwargs)
    return vinkel, intensitet_norm

plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
read_n_plot('NaCl_data.xy', 'k', '--', lw = 1.0)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel(r'$2\theta$')
plt.xlim(0, 65)
plt.ylabel('Intensitet (a.u.)')
plt.tick_params(left=None)
plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Example below uses standard powder XRD data for `NaCl`. It seems the `'--'` argument for `linestyle` didn't get through at all. The legend says there are two plots.

NaCl XRD data duplicate:

[image: NaCl XRD data duplicate]

Comment: So are you trying to using ```plt.plot(*args)``` to replace ```plt.plot(arg1),plt.plot(arg2)```,etc?

Comment: @xpie I'm trying to unpack '*args' so that every argument inside '*args' is passed to a single 'plt.plot()'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By referring to the [official document](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) of `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`, we can find that `linestyle` is a **keyword** argument. This is why your code doesn't work as you expected. Try replace '`--'` with `ls='--'`.

Comment: Thank you! I will be more careful with keyword arguments in the future.